# Extending vs. implementing Comparable in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement binary search tree in java. It can take any object as the data of a node in the tree, as long as that object implements the Comparable interface. This is needed because while putting a new node in the tree, we need to decide, whether the new node is of *lesser* or *greater* value compared to its parent. My Node class looks something like the following.

```
package com.java.ds.bst;

public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<T> {
  private T data;
  private Node<T> left = null;
  private Node<T> right = null;

  public Node() {
    this.data = null;
  }

  public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public T getValue() {
    return this.data;
  }

  public Node<T> getLeft() {
    return this.left;
  }

  public Node<T> getRight() {
    return this.right;
  }

  public void setLeft(Node<T> left) {
    this.left = left;
  }

  public void setRight(Node<T> right) {
    this.right = right;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(T other) {
    return this.data.compareTo(other);
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is, in the class name declaration, why do I need `T extends Comparable<T>` instead of `T implements Comparable<T>`?

Comment: that's the syntax for generic type bounds. `extends` in this context stands for either "extends a class" or "implements an interface"

Comment: The linked duplicate explains generic type bounds. The `extends` keyword means different things in different contexts. You are correct that a class `implement`s an interface, just as your Node does, but a generic type bound does not distinguish between an extending and implementing relationship (because it's not useful to do so).

Comment: @Michael That explains it I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the syntax for generics, `T extends Comparable<T>` means it will accept anything that is `Comparable<T>`.

You are correct to use implements `Comparable<T>` when implementing the interface.